# Can you continue to play an Adventurers League character who was True Polymorphed into a monster?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, dnd-adventurers-league

If your character is transformed into a monster by *true polymorph*, can you legally continue playing them if the effect isn't dispelled?

If not, then what are the ways to be reverted if the session already ended?

Answer (score 31):

## No (kinda<sup>1</sup>), because you can't stay *True Polymorph*ed after the session ends - the effect is *always* dispelled.

During the session, you can keep playing the character. It's still the same entity/person, because *[True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* says:

> It retains its alignment and personality.

After the session, you can't *stay* polymorphed because the [Season 7 FAQ](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208179/DD-Adventurers-League-DM-Pack) updated the rules on *True Polymorph*:

> **True Polymorph**
>
> The following guidance applies:
>
> ***Dragons Aren’t Allowed in Town?!*** The effects of true polymorph are dispelled at the end of the adventure or session — whichever happens first.

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's a "no" under formal logic - the statement of "legal character AND stay True Polymorphed" must be true in both parts for the answer to be "Yes". You can't fulfill both parameters (the second is impossible), so the answer to the question is "No".</sub>

Answer (score 13):

No, once you've been hit with *true polymorph* and it's become permanent, you need to get rid of it to keep using that character. From the [Adventurers' League FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf):

> #### Dragons Aren’t Allowed in Town?!
>
> A character 
>   that ends an adventure as a race or creature not 
>   otherwise available through their character creation 
>   rules is removed from play until the effects of the 
>   true polymorph spell are dispelled.

Comment: The awkward part of this is that the character cannot officially be played, but in order to get the transformation reversed, it needs to officially be brought in to play so the impact of casting the Dispel can be noted. What routes, if any, can a player take to recover their character for more AL play if it ends a session True Polymorphed? (Is that now a separate question? If so, OP may want to ask it, as I don't play AL or have such a character.)

Comment: @NeilSlater The only way I know of is to use spellcasting services in downtime.

Comment: @NeilSlater Well, the character becomes an NPC. But since the victim retains its Int and personality, it seems likely to more or less cooperate with the party, especially if the party is going to seek out a way to undo the curse.

Comment: This information is out of date as of... well, before the answer was posted, actually.

Comment: @NeilSlater just beat yourself down to 0 HP before the adventure or session ends. `If it reverts as a result of Dropping to 0 Hit Points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form.`

Answer (score 1):

You can. As of Season 7 FAQ, True Polymorph is automatically dispelled after every session/module, so you will be reverted to your normal self. If you want to become yourself prior to the end of the session/module, someone will need to dispell the effect.

If you find yourself too big to fit somewhere, you will likely have to wait on a mountaintop somewhere while the rest of the party does its thing. If you can't join them because they went somewhere you can't you'll just have to wait until the session ends and continue along the next time as your normal self.